# Maven jgit JDWP transport error

Tags: java, maven, jgit, jdwp

I have recently begun using jgitflow for maven and have the following issue.

When I run mvn jgitflow:release-start everything works fine, the release branch is created, pom files are updated, etc.

When I try to run mvn jgitflow:release-end I get the following error:

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
ERROR: transport error 202: bind failed: Address already in use
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_socket failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [../../../src/share/back/debugInit.c:690]
```

My MAVEN_OPTS is set to the following:

```
-Xmx1024m -Xms512m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -Duser.timezone=PST -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8213
```

I have verified that 8213 port is not being used, and have changed it several times getting the same result each time.

Any assistance appreciated; thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Via the -Xrunjdwp you enable debugging your Maven execution.

Unless you really need that, remove the -Xrunjdwp:... piece in MAVEN_OPTS and try again, the only thing you will loose is the possibility to debug the maven execution via Eclipse/Netbeans, but you normally would not do that, or?